# What is this place?

Tags: riddle

They brought me to this place last week.

It is a place of knives, wires and pincers. Throughout day and night, the silence is broken by screams of unbearable agony and unprecedented terror.

They put the wires on me and cut me with the knives when the pincers didn't work.

I have slept here more safe and happy than ever before in my life. I think I'd like to come back here.

Where am I?

Comment: who brought you to this place.

Comment: @numberknot that would make the answer too obvious. Maybe I can think of a misleading way to put it though.

Comment: @Emrakul: so given that the sandbox is no more, can I have this un-holded or do I have to repost?

Comment: I've reopened it for you.

Comment: @Deusovi: thanks. And props for being willing to admit the sandbox was a bad decision. I would have added to the discussion, but was occupied... for reasons directly related to the content of the riddle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it

> a birth house? And you are a woman who just gave birth to a baby.
>  It's very painful, and probably this birth was hard, as it even required some surgery (don't know the name for this specific operation in English). But everything went well after all, and you would like to have another baby in the future.

Comment: I think the word you are looking for is a "cesarean section"

Comment: @c.pullen Yes, thanks. It's named the same in Russian, I just didn't know the exact translation.

Comment: Congratulations, you got it :)

Comment: @Verence, you're very welcome

Answer (score 1):

a bit of a long shot but is it

> a restaurant that serves lobster?

as

> they use wires to hold the pincers shut, which would stop the pincers from working and then they would cut the lobster with the knives.

also

> "Throughout the night, the silence is broken by screams of unbearable agony and unprecedented terror." this is the sound of his lobster friends being chosen to be eaten.

thought for the last line

> he wants to go back to the tank where they keep the lobsters as it means he will live longer

Comment: Interesting - the wires/pincers/knives thing matches surprisingly well, but the rest is obviously a big stretch - lobsters don't scream, and restaurants are not open "throughout the night" (and day, I edited that part). And it's just one place, and the tank would hardly be happy for the lobsters.

Comment: I thought it was a stretch but you never know until you ask :), i was thinking the noise the lobsters make when they are boiled sounds a bit like a scream and compared to the boiling pot the tank would be heaven :)

Answer (score 1):

You are in:

> [Room 101](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ministries_of_Nineteen_Eighty-Four#Room_101), from George Orwell's 1984, where your worst nightmares are made to come true.

Comment: Hm, the novel does end with Winston finding happiness in succumbing to the brainwashing. But even in 1984 that wouldn't happen directly in or around Room 101.

Answer (score -1):

I think

> the place is a uterus, they take him out with pincers when there's a caesarian birth

Comment: close, but not quite - you're not brought to the uterus a week before birth. Oh, and the pincers/forceps are not used during a c-section, they're an alternative that might be tried before.